# How can I foreach data of column contains array for ID users?

Tags: json, laravel

I have this table contains column ( attendees ) that column contains id of users

[image]

How can I foreach ( attendees ) column and say if this id = any id of user show name of user , I'd trying with this code but not working

```
@foreach ($view->attendees as $test)
   <p>{{ $test }}</p>
@endforeach
```

any help pls ?

Comment: Rather than storing the attendee ID's in an array on the column you should set them up with a pivot table so you can define a `belongsToMany` relation. That way you can use eager loading to retrieve all the users and have better data integrity enforced by the DB itself. Short of that you can do `$attendees 
 = User::whereIn('id', $view->attendees)->get()`

Comment: sorry , don't catch it . Can you explain more then that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `json_decode()` function, i.e:

```
@foreach (\User::find(json_decode($view->attendees)) as $test)
   <p>{{ $test->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks  man , but show me just the number , I want to say if  any id in array = any user id show me the name of user . and thanks again

Comment: Just add `$test->name` to @dparoli's code should do the trick